Issue in docker run projects (Could not find or load main class MainKt)
I have two folders

my-app (react app)
shopBacked (Kotlin project create using intellij)
I want to create my projects using docker. I created 3 files: Dockerfile in my-app to run react app, Dockerfile in shopBacked to run my kotlin project. And last: docker-compose.yml in root folder.
i run my code: docker-compose up --build and my-app ran correctly but kotlin project doesn't work.
I chacked the logs and result:
backend-1  | Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt
backend-1  | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainKt

My docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build: 
      context: ./shopBacked
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - app-network

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./my-app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

Dockerfile for backend:
FROM openjdk:11-jdk

WORKDIR /app

COPY build/libs/shopBacked-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/shopBacked.jar

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "shopBacked.jar"]


build.gardle.kts:
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.0"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.0"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val springBootVersion = "2.7.0"
val jacksonModuleKotlinVersion = "2.13.1"
val seleniumVersion = "3.141.59"
val junitJupiterVersion = "5.6.0"


dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$jacksonModuleKotlinVersion")
    implementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:$seleniumVersion")
    implementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:$junitJupiterVersion")
}

kotlin {
}


tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.Application"
    }
}

What is incorrect? If i run my server using intellij everything is correctly.
I tried to change build.gardle.kts and i analyze name of my jar file (and path) but its still doesn't work
